The issue with using async/await and then() together
Most of my functions are written like this, but I noticed in Sentry that the error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined is being logged frequently. Could it be that using async/await together with then is causing the code to reference undefined?
const handleAPI8_8 = async () => {
    const result = await homeTabApiController['8_8']();
    if (result) {
      setHasWaitingGathering(true);
    } else {
      setHasWaitingGathering(false);
    }
  };

 '8_8': async () => {
    return await axios({
      url: homeTab['8_8'](),
      method: 'get',
    }).then(res => {
      const data: boolean = res.data.value;
      return data;
    });
  },

I have confirmed that the server does not return undefined to me.

No, such an error is not caused by interaction of .then() with async/await. It simply means that your server responded with a JSON value that does not contain .data.value.

Thank you! But then, what does this mean in the context of this link? Did I misunderstand it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458348/data-undefined-in-axios-response

The problem there was that the callback passed to .then() did not return anything. Your callback does return data;, the code is fine (although it would be cleaner using only await).
